# 502 Bad Gateway nginx docker

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx

I have php, nginx, mysql, phpmyadmin in Docker and the are running all.
But I can not use any othe them because, when I visit the localhost it shows me the following Error: 502 Bad Gateway

[image: that is the directory of my projet]

[image: see all are running]
I don't know why, I tried alot to know the reason but Icound't figure it out.
That is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
          
RUN apt update   \
            && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
            && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
            && pecl install apcu \
            && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
            && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
            && docker-php-ext-install zip
WORKDIR /var/www/infoSystem
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN git config --global user.email "test@gmail.com" \
        && git config --global user.name  "test"




FROM node:12.13.0
RUN apt update
WORKDIR /var/www/infoSystem
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]
USER node
```

`entrypoint.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
# Prevent container from shutting down
while true; do sleep 3600; done
```

`default.conf` file

```
server {

    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/infoSystem/public;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    location / {
        try_files  $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \\.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

`docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: alsbls
      MYSQL_DATABASE: infoSystem
      MYSQL_USER: alsbls
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: alsbls
    ports:
      - '4306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    container_name: php
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/infoSystem

    depends_on:
      - database

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/infoSystem
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - database

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_USER: alsbls_root
      PMA_PASSWORD: alsbls_root
    ports:
      - "8081:81"

  encore:
    container_name: node
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/infoSystem
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error occurs due php container isn't running.

Could you check wich the Dockerfile below?

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm
      
RUN apt update   \
            && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
            && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
            && pecl install apcu \
            && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
            && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
            && docker-php-ext-install zip
WORKDIR /var/www/infoSystem
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN git config --global user.email "devojob97@gmail.com" \
        && git config --global user.name  "alsbls"

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

After adding the code for php.

You have to execute the following commadn to solve the problem:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/app:/var/www/infoSystem  -w /var/www/infoSystem -it node:12.13.0 bash
```

this answer was from @Artem

Comment: that's working, but I can not use yarn.
When I write `yarn -v`  it gives me command nout found.
Could you please tell me how to install yarn with Docker?
thx

Comment: Could you use yarn in a separate container?

Comment: how can I connect it with my main docker container?

Comment: Do you use yarn only for building assets? If yes, you can use the common volume

Comment: Yeah I use it for assets and to add or remove plugins

Comment: You can use it without docker compose. Just use a command something like this `docker run --rm -v ./app:/var/www/infoSystem -w /var/www/infoSystem node:12.13.0 bash -c "yarn install && yarn build"`

Comment: I runed your command and  I got the following error


`docker: Error response from daemon: create ./app: "./app" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'. `

Comment: I wrote the wrong command. Please use it: 
`docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/app:/var/www/infoSystem  -w /var/www/infoSystem node:12.13.0 bash -c "yarn install && yarn build"`

Comment: I runed the new command and it was success:
that is the message after I runed the command:

webpack compiled successfully


But when I go inside the docker container and run 
`yarn -v` I become an error 
`bash: docker: command not found.`
Or when I run yarn install I become the same error

`bash: docker: command not found`

Comment: Using this command `docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/app:/var/www/infoSystem  -w /var/www/infoSystem -it node:12.13.0 bash` you will run and go inside a container right away

Comment: Thank you very much bro, I appreciate your help for me.
Now I can work on my project for learning :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242217/discussion-between-dr-it79-and-artem).

Answer (score 0):

You are running docker multi-stage build.

FROM php:8.0-fpm

....
then
....

FROM node:12.13.0

This doesn't mean that php-fpm is being merged within single container with node. Multi-stage is being used to mostly to get files from the earlier image. The last "FROM" would be the final image of the container.

Thus you might want to either remove node / move node earlier / install node differently

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).